# How to track if drawer is closed on side screen tap?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Basically the title is my question. Is there a way to add any tap events and track that drawer is closed without any button click?

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget (CardStack oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    print('CardStack didUpdateWidget isDrawerOpen: ${Scaffold.of(context).isDrawerOpen}');
    print('CardStack didUpdateWidget isEndDrawerOpen: ${Scaffold.of(context).isEndDrawerOpen}');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Scaffold` state provides `isDrawerOpen` and `isEndDrawerOpen`.

You can assign a `GlobalKey` to `Scaffold` to be able to get a reference from anywhere in your app using this `GlobalKey`.

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/isDrawerOpen.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/isEndDrawerOpen.html

Comment: isDrawerOpen or isEndDrawerOpen is never change when you click on the side of the screen to close the drawer

Comment: It should be, at least after the open/close animation is completed.

Comment: Well I'm checking in the widget update method
it only changes on open and close if the drawer closed using a button, but doesn't work on animation end (

Comment: Please add the code to your question (properly formatted). Code in comments is unreadable.